# Word for "extinct", "eradicated" that sounds like "reserved"

Tags: rhymes, puns

In the Czech language, there's a word play with copyright notice. We say "vyhrazena" for "reserved" (as of *rights*) and "vyhlazena" as for eradicated (eg. Indians).

I used that pun on my mini site footer and now I don't know how to translate it, to keep the joke in it. So far, I just translated it: "*All rights erradicated, copy and let others copy too*."

Do you have any ideas for similar wordplay in English?

Comment: I can't think of a way of making an actual translation of the pun, but you can make a different pun based on the various meanings of _reserve_, like “All rights reserved for another day—go ahead and copy away” (couldn't help adding a rhyme, too).

Comment: Anything is welcome.

Comment: All copy rights granted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was thinking of "All rights **reversed**", and as I googled it, I found out that the pun is actually being used with the same meaning you're looking for:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/All_rights_reversed

Comment: Oh - yeah, I even use that reversed copyright symbol. Thank you very much.

Comment: Glad I could help!

Answer (score 1):

How about "*all rights unreserved, copy and let others copy too.*"?

Answer (score 1):

All rights are off the reservation. It sounds like a Czech-to-English translation error but the pun would be that rights aren't reserved sort of like a tribe is off the reservation. I would consider it a bit offensive, but I think Sherman Alexie would think it's funny.